# strange and complext recurrence relation example?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algorithms, recurrence-relations

I have a recurrence as follows:

$T(n)= \sqrt n  T (\sqrt n ) +n \log n$

I see this TA solved example as final answer $O(n^2 \log n)$.

> Is there any idea how I can solve it easily?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Does https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/140736/how-to-solve-tn-4t-sqrtn-3-log-n2-with-the-master-theorem/140744#140744 help you? It isn't the same but go through my answer and the comments on my answer. You should get the required hint and the motivation of how to solve it. Reply back if you are still stuck.

Comment: @bigbang I see it, but it not related. not clear idea really.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are trying to get others to do your homework.

Comment: The first comment is copied from the “this” link post?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$T(n) = \sqrt{n} T(\sqrt{n})+n \log n= \sqrt{n} (n^{1/4}T(n^{1/4})+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n} \log n)+n \log n = n^{3/4} T(n^{1/4}) + \frac{3}{2} n \log n$$

Seen this you can prove by induction on $k$ that the general form is

$$T(n) = n^q T(n^{1/2k}) + 2(\sum_{i=1}^ k (\frac{1}{2})^i)\cdot n \log n$$

where $q = \sum_{i=1}^k (\frac{1}{2})^i$ which is easy to see that it is $O(n^2 \log n)$. Indeed it should be also $O(n \log n)$.